# Omitting the initializer list entry for data member object

Tags: c++

I have read that it is highly recommend that all data members, regardless of type, are initialized when a class is created and that the initializer list of the constructor is the best place to do this.

What about data members that are objects? Assuming that object has a default initializer that suffices,  is it considered good practice to omit them from the initializer?

Such as:

```
class A{
private:
  AnotherClass B;
  int x;
public:
  A():x(5){} //B is never explicitly initialized
};
```

Comment: If you initialize, say, 4 out of 5 members, I would be confused and wonder why you missed one. Typing a `B()` doesn't cost you much.

Comment: @BoPersson's point is quite valid and hard to disagree with. Still, I find myself omitting the initialisation of things like `std::vector<T>` members, when the default-initialisation suffices. Just one of those things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use member initializer list for initializing members which are of user defined type the default constructor of that particular type will be called to initialize the member object.

So as long as your members have default constructors available and that is your intent, it is perfectly fine.

> **Is it considered good practice to omit them from the initializer?**

It is a matter of choice and preference. For me member initializer lists are more intuitive so i prefer them.

Comment: The above discussion applies only for the specific case you question about and not the advantages of initializing object in Member initializer list vs assigning them in constructor body.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's perfectly fine.

Suppose you have a very complex class, which contains a lot of members, most of them objects, which do have default constructor. As their default constructor will be called, you have nothing to worry about - they will still be initialized.

It's recommended to initialize all members from the standard types (like `int`, `bool`, etc), because they don't have default values.

In your case - if `B` does not have a default constructor, you'll have a compilation error and then you must initialize `B` in `A::A`.